# Unable to read html from ajax data

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax call like following

```
 $("#createnewlist").live('click', function (event) {

    $("#ajax-loading-01").show();
    var createlink = $(this);
    var accountid = createlink.parent().find("input:hidden[name='accountid']").val();
    var listname = createlink.parent().find("input[name='listname']").val();

    //create an ajaxmanager named cacheQueue
    var ajaxManager = $.manageAjax.create('cacheQueue', {
        queue: true,
        cacheResponse: false
    });

    ajaxManager.add(({
        type: 'GET', url: '/ajaxhandler',
        data: { createwishlist: "true", accountid: accountid, listname: listname }

      , success: function (data) {
          alert(data)
          $(".grid03").html($(data).find(".grid03").html());
      }

    }));

});
```

in success I gets whole data in **alert(data)** line

```
  <!-- ActionHandler IS included -->
<p class="favtext">for at folde den ud...</p>
<div class="query-input lynlistesearcher">
  <label>Søg i dine Lynlister</label>
  <input type="text" name="textbox" id="txtesearch" />
</div>
<div class="grid03">
  <ul>  
    <li>
      <div class="head-text">
        <strong data-id="149658491" class="149658491"></strong>
        <a rel="149658491" class="deletelistclass" rev="74123311" href="#">
          <translate key="delete-list">Slet liste</translate>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

but when i try to fetch html from this data

```
$(data).find(".grid03").html()
```

It gives null.
Can anyone give any clue?

Comment: Can you show us what you have in data?

Comment: Are you trying to find this class `grid03` in your data?

Comment: @DeadMan.Yes.I have updated my question with html i get in alert

Comment: @Adil:I have updated question with Data .please take a look

Comment: are you getting any errors.. cause your code looks fine to me...

Comment: `ajaxManager.add(({` you have double `((` is it correct?

Comment: @bipen nop,I am not getting any errors

Comment: @Jai: Removing that one(()) also not helped.any way i am not geting any errors.

Comment: @AKS You can try with this: `$(".grid03").html($(data).find(".grid03 ul").html());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), so changing:

```
$(".grid03").html($(data).find(".grid03").html());
```

to

```
$(".grid03").html($(data).filter("div.grid03").html());
```

Comment: That worked like a magic. can you explain me what was wrong with old one.

Comment: @AKS, divs are top level elements and your response data isn't an element but a string, so you will need to use filter() instead of find()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".grid03").html($(data).eq(2).find(".grid03").html());
```